# D3JS V5 cannot build fixed size of slices of legend when data updated

Tags: d3.js, heatmap

I want to have my legend with 9 gradations. When the data updated, only the legend text will be changed. I cannot make it through the code below. When I updated the data, the number of gradation will be changed based on new data's min and max values. I set ticks(9) but is does not work. Any suggestions on how to tweak it? Fixed range of scale is not preferred.

```
var z = d3.scaleLinear().range(["#fff7f3", "#49006a"])
    z.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.count}))

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend").remove()  
    legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(z.ticks(9).slice(1).reverse())    
        .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" +   
                 -(-290 + i * 35) + "," + 415 + ")"; })

    legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 35)
        .attr("height", 25)
        .style("fill", z)

    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", -1)
        .attr("y", 35)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(String)
        .attr("font-size", "11px")
```

Comment: Could you create a codepen or jsfiddle so that we can review other code?

Comment: Never mind, I know how to do it. I changed scaleLinear to scaleQuantile